# NOT NULL constraint failed: baseapi_movie.admin_id without using django forms

Tags: python, django

I created Theimdb movie API and I store all the  movies' data into database but I got error when I used foreign key.some users liked different film so I want show different user can see different data, so I used model relationship, can anyone please suggest me how to do it.

```
views.py


@login_required(redirect_field_name="log")
def trending(request):
    movie_list=[]
    try:
        if request.method=="POST":
            if "taskAdd" in request.POST:
                title=request.POST["title"]
                release=request.POST["release"]
                poster=request.POST["poster"]
                vote_average=request.POST["vote_average"]
                movie_id=request.POST["movie_id"]
                task=Movie(title=title,release=release,poster=poster,vote_average=vote_average,movie_id=movie_id)
                task.save()
                return redirect('/')
```

```
models.py

class Movie(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(verbose_name='movie_name',max_length=30)
    #overview=models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    release=models.DateField()
    poster=models.ImageField(upload_to=None, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)
    vote_average=models.CharField(max_length=30,default=True)
    movie_id=models.IntegerField(default=True)
    admin=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: you are missing admin while adding a movie

Comment: May I kindly suggest you'd be better using django forms? Submitting unsanitized unvalidated user inputs to your db is very bad idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add admin in while creating a movie like below

```
task=Movie(
 title=title,
 release=release,
 poster=poster,
 vote_average=vote_average,
 movie_id=movie_id,
 admin=request.user
)
task.save()
```